# Compiled Bitcoin Client as Testnet with bitcoin.conf

Tags: client, api, bitcoin.conf

I'm quite new to bitcoin. I've been compiling the client from github and I want to run on a server as testnet and make some API requests. As I see in the documentation I should create a bitcoin.conf file. But where do I create this in case of compiled client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of your bitcoin.conf file depends on your operating system: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File

Note that you can also pass any configuration value as command line argument.

Comment: thank you for your feedback I've been compiling on linux but when I check /home/user/.bitcoin folder do not exists. There is a bitcoin folder from I compiled the source

Comment: If that folder does not exist, just create it!

Comment: okay cool I will give a try

Comment: if you run bitcoind with sudo the .bitcoin folder is created in /root/.bitcoin as im aware. If run without root its created in /home/user/.bitcoin . However, bitcoin does create the folder upon first start.

Answer (score 0):

The bitcoin.conf file has to be created within the .bitcoin folder.